# ASP.Net Core injecting setting

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-1.0

In ASP.Net Core it's possible to inject config values into a class using `IOptions<T>`.

So if I have the following `appsettings.json` config:

```
{
  "CustomSection": {
    "Foo": "Bar"
  },
  "RootUrl": "http://localhost:12345/"
}
```

I can inject `IOptions<CustomSection>` into my constructor (assuming I've defined a `CustomSection` class) and read the `Foo` property.

How can I inject the `RootUrl` setting into my constructor or is this not supported?

Comment: you cannot construct a class of `RootUrl`

Comment: You should [not inject IOptions<T> into your constructors](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/143#issuecomment-155029876).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs 
[Using options and configuration objects](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#options-config-objects) that is **not possible**:

> The options pattern enables using custom options classes to represent a group of related settings. A class needs to have a public read-write property for each setting and a constructor that does not take any parameters (e.g. a default constructor) in order to be used as an options class.

That means you need to generate a class to read it's configuration value(s). But in your sample `RootUrl`cannot be constructed via a class.

Answer (score 8):

Create a class as below

```
public class AppSettings {
    public string RootUrl{ get; set; }
}
```

Inject it into your startup.cs as below.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
}
```

And use it in your controller as below.

```
public CustomerController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
{
    [variable] = appSettings.Value;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: No that doesn't work because there is no section called 'AppSettings' in the config file.

Comment: @KaiG You can just use RootUrl, try it.

Comment: No, that throws an Exception when you try to use the setting because it can't parse the string into the expected format. I believe the accepted answer above is correct - it's not supported.

Comment: This would work find if you change to services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);